# Web API Complex type property always null

Tags: jquery, asp.net-web-api

I've this Book class:

```
public class Book
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

This Book ApiController with a post-method using a *Complex type* parameter:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/book")]
public class BookController : ApiController
{
    [Route("create")]
    public Book CreateBook([FromBody]Book book)
    {
        // Persist the book
        return book;
    }
}
```

I'm then using this jQuery code to test my Post-method:

```
var data = {"name":"test"};

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "api/book/create",
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (result) {
        alert(result);
    }
});
```

When running the jQuery, a breakpoint inside my *CreaetBook* action is trigged, but the Book.Name property is `null`. I expect it to be `test`.

Why is it always null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try without `JSON.stringify`

```
var data = {"name":"test"};

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "api/book/create",
    data: data,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (result) {
        alert(result);
    }
});
```